# Postgres query selection logic

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, generated-columns

```sql
CREATE TYPE edition AS ENUM (
    'b',
    'j'
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS versions (
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    edition edition NOT NULL,
    major integer NOT NULL,
    minor integer NOT NULL,
    patch integer NOT NULL,
    cycle decimal GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
        CAST(
            (CAST(major AS text) || '.' || CAST(minor AS text)) AS decimal
        )
    ) STORED
);

INSERT INTO versions
    (edition, major, minor, patch)
VALUES
    ('b', 1, 16, 0),
    ('b', 1, 17, 0),
    ('b', 1, 18, 0),
    ('b', 1, 19, 0),
    ('j', 1, 16, 0),
    ('j', 1, 17, 0),
    ('j', 1, 18, 0),
    ('j', 1, 19, 0)
;
```

I'm building a web application to reference various aspects of Minecraft. I'm trying to build a stored generated column in my `versions` table to specify if the record in question specifies the highest version number, per edition. (Minecraft is published as two separate and incompatible editions: Bedrock (`b`) and Java (`j`).)

Given the structure and data above, I expect the following select to return `true` only once for each `is_latest_*` field and `false` for all others.

```sql
SELECT
    *,
    (
        edition = 'b'
        AND GREATEST(major) = major
        AND GREATEST(minor) = minor
        AND GREATEST(patch) = patch
    ) AS is_latest_bedrock,
    (
        edition = 'j'
        AND GREATEST(major) = major
        AND GREATEST(minor) = minor
        AND GREATEST(patch) = patch
    ) AS is_latest_java
FROM versions
ORDER BY edition, major, minor, patch;
```

What I am instead seeing is that every record is marked as the highest version for each respective edition:

| id | edition | major | minor | patch | cycle | is_latest_bedrock | is_latest_java |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ddcdc01f-7ac1-4c4a-be7f-5e93902a0855 | b | 1 | 16 | 0 | 1.16 | true | false |
| 20d1bf38-75d6-4d96-94fc-fd16d2131319 | b | 1 | 17 | 0 | 1.17 | true | false |
| 13252697-4fe6-411f-b151-e4a1ca146e2f | b | 1 | 18 | 0 | 1.18 | true | false |
| 16a1eb78-e566-4649-991c-3ecdd8e6f49b | b | 1 | 19 | 0 | 1.19 | true | false |
| 5ef4657a-c4fc-41f4-b2e1-0aa88e0e4b07 | j | 1 | 16 | 0 | 1.16 | false | true |
| f68cebf4-a62d-45c5-af67-098f8be041a3 | j | 1 | 17 | 0 | 1.17 | false | true |
| bd37ff94-5a62-4fc7-a729-6fc353a7c939 | j | 1 | 18 | 0 | 1.18 | false | true |
| 09293db6-aa6b-4cc4-8a58-29afba816d85 | j | 1 | 19 | 0 | 1.19 | false | true |

Here is the result set I expect/want to see:

| id | edition | major | minor | patch | cycle | is_latest_bedrock | is_latest_java |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ddcdc01f-7ac1-4c4a-be7f-5e93902a0855 | b | 1 | 16 | 0 | 1.16 | false | false |
| 20d1bf38-75d6-4d96-94fc-fd16d2131319 | b | 1 | 17 | 0 | 1.17 | false | false |
| 13252697-4fe6-411f-b151-e4a1ca146e2f | b | 1 | 18 | 0 | 1.18 | false | false |
| 16a1eb78-e566-4649-991c-3ecdd8e6f49b | b | 1 | 19 | 0 | 1.19 | true | false |
| 5ef4657a-c4fc-41f4-b2e1-0aa88e0e4b07 | j | 1 | 16 | 0 | 1.16 | false | false |
| f68cebf4-a62d-45c5-af67-098f8be041a3 | j | 1 | 17 | 0 | 1.17 | false | false |
| bd37ff94-5a62-4fc7-a729-6fc353a7c939 | j | 1 | 18 | 0 | 1.18 | false | false |
| 09293db6-aa6b-4cc4-8a58-29afba816d85 | j | 1 | 19 | 0 | 1.19 | false | true |

How can I update the query to mark only one Bedrock version and one Java version as the latest?

Comment: Why are you using UUIDs as a PK when your data contains a natural composite key?

Comment: Use MAX() not GREATEST.  So MAX() is typically used to return the maximum value in a column in a database. The table could contain many rows, but this function returns the one with the maximum value.

GREATEST() on the other hand, returns the maximum-valued argument from the list of arguments passed to it. So you could pass say, 3 arguments to this function and it will return the one with the largest value.

Comment: @Dai I just use UUIDs for primary keys as a matter of course. Also I'm going to be referencing this table with many foreign keys, and having a single column primary key is simpler.

Comment: @Mehrwarz I realize that now. I can't use `MAX()` in a non-aggregate result set. I wasn't familiar with `GREATEST()`, and I assumed it would consider all values in the specified column, not just the value for the record in question.

Comment: Your generated column `cycle` shouldn't be a numeric column. Version numbers work differently! `1.19 > 1.2`. An integer array would sort properly: `ARRAY[major, minor)]` - See: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/74298/3684  That said, don't add a generated column for this at all. Generate the combined version number for display on the fly with `concat_ws('.', major, minor) AS cycle`. Cheaper overall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ROW_NUMBER](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-window-function/postgresql-row_number/) window function, and partitioning over the `edition` types may be a good solution for this case - where you want to still return all records.

See the below query,  which windows over the `edition` types and assigns a row number to each record, sorted by `major`, `minor`, `patch` in descending order.  For generating a boolean for the latest result,  `= 1` is used to just assert whether this record is the first in the ordering of the window. A pro to this route is it will output an indicator for *any* `edition` type in the table that may be added in the future.

Query:

```
SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY edition ORDER BY major desc, minor desc, patch desc) = 1 as is_latest_version_for_edition
FROM versions
ORDER BY edition, major, minor, patch;
```

Result:

| id | edition | major | minor | patch | cycle | is_latest_version_for_edition |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6ef44cf8-10d6-4cb9-874a-ff9322ce708b | b | 1 | 16 | 0 | 1.16 | false |
| 9d5fc712-819f-4d9d-ada7-fa5371ae1a7e | b | 1 | 17 | 0 | 1.17 | false |
| 046c76f2-c8be-4686-ab0d-1387fd798579 | b | 1 | 18 | 0 | 1.18 | false |
| 3ba9b494-acf4-4eda-ae46-b305abebf93d | b | 1 | 19 | 0 | 1.19 | true |
| 87c2552b-3591-416a-baa1-6297b3b0e6c2 | j | 1 | 16 | 0 | 1.16 | false |
| 51872b9b-ec3f-45d3-8be7-532946b699a8 | j | 1 | 17 | 0 | 1.17 | false |
| 2205b1df-4d7b-4eee-ac17-c153f2374339 | j | 1 | 18 | 0 | 1.18 | false |
| f65635e4-e687-4a30-a69d-9154b6d61dd6 | j | 1 | 19 | 0 | 1.19 | true |

DbFiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sB7zE1syp8xNmnEk2oizCR/0

Comment: That's basically perfect, but I didn't know I can't use windowing functions in column generation expressions. Also the window only seems to consider the result set, so if I filter `WHERE minor < 19`, it returns `true` for `minor = 18`.

Comment: @ravinggenius: If you need to add filters, you must determine the latest from the whole table separately, but that was not in your question.

Comment: Yes it will consider the resultset only,  if you need to filter,  wrap that query in a subquery and then apply your filtering.  You need the whole resultset to determine what is the latest anyway, then you would need to filter afterwards.  See https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/u4XyWHb9NNnU5uTLFG3BQL/1

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter you are correct. I can just use a sub-select to filter the result correctly. I intended to adapt this answer to a column generation expression, which wouldn't be a problem for filtering without a sub-select.